# How to refer a rotated full size image as table?

Tags: tables, floats, errors

I use a big excel generated table screenshoted in my latex document.
I need to lable it as table but I always get an error.

```
    \begin{sidewaysfigure}[ht]
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{p1.jpg}
    \caption{Tabellarische Zusammenfassung der wichtigsten Vergleichskriterien}
    \label{Tabellarische Zusammenfassung der ermittelten Vergleichskriterien}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
```

If I pack it in table code like this:

```
\begin{table}[htb]

    \begin{sidewaysfigure}[ht]
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{p1.jpg}
        \caption{Tabellarische Zusammenfassung der wichtigsten Vergleichskriterien}
        \label{Tabellarische Zusammenfassung der ermittelten Vergleichskriterien}
    \end{sidewaysfigure}

\end{table}
```

I get an error:

```
Not in outer par mode. \begin{sidewaysfigure}[ht]
```

hope you can help me :)

Comment: Hello, welcome to TeX.SE! Please provide a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) (starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`) so that people can reproduce your problem. You can use the `example-image` inside `\includegraphics`, it is always available.

Comment: Why not use the `sidewaystable` environment?